# How to setup a profile page that is only visible to logged in users?

Tags: wordpress, profile, forms

When I setup a new Profile, it is available to everybody publicly that has the link but I want to limit access to only logged in users (or even users in a specific group).

I think this should be simple but for some reason I am missing how to do this.

Comment: I have removed the webform-civicrm tag from this post as you have added WP and they are mutually exclusive (you weren't to know) as webform-civicrm is a Drupal module.

Comment: for several of your questions it seems like you may be pushing the limit for Profiles. In drupal we can work around those limitations with webform-civicrm and views (for displaying info). I wonder if you need to investigate SearchKit and Afform to get more of what you are after, rather than the rather simpler concept of Profiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well maybe somebody has a better way of doing this, but this is how I ended up accomplishing this...

Using the buildForm hook, I checked the Contact ID of the user accessing the form, and if there was no Contact ID then they were not logged, so I then used jQuery to completely replace the form on the page with the text "You do not have permission to view this page!"

Code looks like this:

```
// Check if it is a Profile form with specific id (15 in this case)
if ( $formName == 'CRM_Profile_Form_Edit' && $form->getVar('_gid') == 15 ) {

  // What user is trying to access the form?
  $whatUser = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', [
      'sequential' => 1,
      'return' => ["id"],
      'id' => "user_contact_id",
    ]);

  // Check if user id is set
  if ( isset($whatUser['id']) ) {
    // User id is set so a user must be logged in
    $okToShowPage = true;
  } else {
    // No user id so user is not logged in
    $okToShowPage = false;
  }
  
  if ($okToShowPage) {
    // Just let the profile page display as usually and do nothing.
    
  } else {
    // Completely delete DIV with id=crm-container and replace it with a new DIV
    CRM_Core_Region::instance('page-body')->add( ['script' => "cj('#crm-container').replaceWith('<div><b>You do not have permission to view this page.</b></div>');"] );
  }

}
```